# Doubt formalizing one-step extensions of ZFC:

Tags: set-theory

From Kunen's book:

[image]

I was wondering how to write down formally the $\phi$ sentences (in a way that the proof I need to provide gets easy) for:

$0$ the constant symbol: $\phi(y)=\forall{x}(({x}\in{y})\land(x\ne{x}))$

$\{x_1,x_2\}$, the 2-place pair symbol: $\phi(x_1,x_2,y)=\forall{x}(({x}\in{y})\land(({x}={x_1})\lor({x}={x_2}))$

${x_1}\cap{x_2}$ the 2-place intersection symbol: $\phi(x_1,x_2,y)=\forall{x}(({x}\in{y})\land({x}\in{x_1})\land({x}\in{x_2}))$

Are these definitions right and convenient?

Or maybe it is better to write them as:
$\phi(x_1,x_2,y)=\forall{x}\in{y}[\phi_1(x_1,x_2,x)]$

And for the pair function $\phi_1(x_1,x_2,x) = ({x}={x_1})\lor({x}={x_2})$

As a followup, I'm not sure at all how to write the formal proof especially the uniqueness of the set $y$. I should use extensionality, and somehow assuming there are two sets, proving the two are equal. But when trying to write down explicitly in paper, I get lost at some point... I suspect the unicity is the same pattern for all three cases.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE: new definitions

$0$ the constant symbol: $\phi(y)=\forall{x}({x}\in{y}\leftrightarrow{x}\ne{x})$

$\{x_1,x_2\}$, the 2-place pair symbol: $\phi(x_1,x_2,y)=\forall{x}({x}\in{y}\leftrightarrow({x}={x_1})\lor({x}={x_2}))$

${x_1}\cap{x_2}$ the 2-place intersection symbol: $\phi(x_1,x_2,y)=\forall{x}({x}\in{y}\leftrightarrow({x}\in{x_1})\land({x}\in{x_2}))$

Let's focus on the first:

$\phi(y)=\forall{x}({x}\in{y}\leftrightarrow{x}\ne{x})$

I need to prove
$S\vdash \exists!{y}\phi(y)$

It's the same as proving $S\vdash \exists y(\phi(y) \land \forall z(\phi(z) \rightarrow z=y))$

brrr... I don't know how to proof that...

EDIT2:

Comment: All your definitions are wrong in the same way. For example, $\forall x( x\in y \land x\ne x$) should be $\forall x( x\in y \leftrightarrow x\ne x)$... the former expression with "$\land$" instead of "$\leftrightarrow$" is just false all the time regardless if $y$ is the empty set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axiom schema of separation is (for any formula $\psi(x)$ in which $y$ does not occur) $$ \forall A\exists y\forall x( x\in y\leftrightarrow x\in A\land\psi(x)).$$ By the set existence axiom, $\exists A\; A=A,$ and we also have $x\ne x\leftrightarrow x\ne x\land x\in A,$ so we can instantiate an $A$ and apply separation on that $A$ with $\psi(x) :=x\ne x,$ to give $$ \exists y \forall x ( x\in y\leftrightarrow x\ne x),$$ i.e. $\exists y\phi(y)$, for your definition of $\phi$.

The axiom of extensionality is $$\forall y,z ( \forall x( x\in y\leftrightarrow x\in z) \to y = z ),$$ and this is what guarantees uniqueness.

In more detail, we have $$\phi(y)\to \forall x(x\in y\leftrightarrow x\ne x ) $$ and $$\phi(y')\to \forall x(x\in y'\leftrightarrow x\ne x ),$$ so $$\phi(y)\land \phi(y')\to \forall x(x\in y\leftrightarrow x\in y'),$$ so by the axiom of extensionality, $$ \phi(y)\land \phi(y')\to y=y'.$$

Thus, since $\exists y \phi(y),$ we have $$ \exists y (\phi(y)\land \forall y' ( \phi(y')\to y'=y )),$$ i.e. $\exists !y \phi(y).$

Comment: But the Comprehension Schema (what you say separation I guess) the book use is:
$\forall{z}\forall{w_1},...,{w_n}\exists{y}\forall{x}(x\in{y}\leftrightarrow {x}\in{z} \land \phi)$

Comment: @Eduard Oh wow... don't know what I was thinking... I really screwed this up (the axiom scheme I wrote down and used is, quite famously, inconsistent). Edited.

Comment: The instantiation of comprehension should have the set A isn't it? Like $ \exists y \forall x ( x\in y\leftrightarrow x\in A \land x\ne x)$

Comment: Or how do you prove $x\ne x\leftrightarrow x\ne x\land x\in A$?

Comment: @Eduard It's a logical validity (both sides of the biequivalence are always false).

Comment: Ok. I see. For the generality of the $\exists!$ argument the key point is whatever $\psi(x)$ you choose make sure that $\psi(x) \leftrightarrow \psi(x) \land {x}\in{A}$ for whatever A your are able to make using set existence axioms...

Comment: In general if $$\phi(y):=\forall{x}({x}\in{y}\leftrightarrow\psi(x))$$

And there is a set A such as
$$\psi(x) \leftrightarrow \psi(x) \land {x}\in{A}$$

Then $\exists !y \phi(y)$.

So $\phi$ becomes a valid formula from a "one-step extensional" point of view (to add functions in our language).

Comment: Do you know if this $\phi$ or $\psi$ have proper names in logic? Like extensioner, extensionalizer, or whatever..

Comment: @Eduard Yes. e.g. for the unordered pair, you get your "$A$" from (Kunen's version of) the axiom of pairing $\forall x_1,x_2 \exists A( x_1\in A\land x_2\in A),$ and take $\psi(x) := x=x_1\lor x=x_2,$ and then we have $\psi(x)\leftrightarrow \psi(x)\land x\in A,$ etc.

Comment: @Eduard Nothing official I'm aware of.

Comment: And for reiterating myself (I'm rereading the book), $\psi$ is what you need to add into the comprehension schema and $\phi$ is what you need to add into the one-step extension.